# What is the correct trigger for activating a google sheets script, when a user submits data into a connected form?

Tags: api, events, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have attached the following script to a Google spreadsheet, so the user gets a notification when submitting a form. When I run it in script editor, it works, but when I submit data in the actual live form attached to the spreadsheet, it doesn't.

I've tried all triggers for running the script but I've received no emails.

here is the code:

```
function sniffEmailAddress(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();   

  // get email
  var dataRangeEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3 ); // 3 is the email col
  var emailAddress = dataRangeEmail.getValue();

  // get names
  var dataRangeFName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2 ); // 3 is the fName col
  var fName = dataRangeFName.getValue();

  // get messege
  var dataRangeMessege = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4 ); // 3 is the Messege col
  var message = dataRangeMessege.getValue();


  // Log
  Logger.log(emailAddress);

  var message = "Hi "+fName+", \nThanks for contacting us. You will be contacted shortly.\n Your messege: \n"+message;
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";


  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trigger should be From Spreadsheet > on Form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I think I found the reason. It seems I should have declared an event object in my function.

```
function sniffEmailAddress(evtObj){....}
```

Not sure but I think this fixed it.

Regards,
CBRCODER